# js / jquery: How to randomize images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, random

I have a script that replaces an image every time the countdown reaches 0. Although I was wondering if it was possible, and how, I could get these images (I have simply just listed in order) to randomize each time the page is refreshed ect.

Here is all of the code *(the images are located before " // Fill in images in this array")*:

```
<div id="counter_2" class="counter">     
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- The ready() function will force the browser to run wait running the javascript until the entire page has loaded -->
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // The jquery code for constructing and starting the counter
        // has been wrapped inside a function so we can call it whenever we want to
        function startCounter(imageLoader){
            $('#counter_2').countdown({
                 image: 'img/digits.png',
                 startTime: '00:10',
                 timerEnd: function(){ callback(imageLoader) },
                 format: 'mm:ss'
            })
        }
        // Takes care of whatever need to be done everytime
        function callback(imageLoader){
            // Replace image
            $('#image').attr('src', imageLoader.nextImage());
            $('#counter_2').empty(); // Clear the finished counter, so a new can be constructed in its place
            startCounter(imageLoader); // Construct a new counter and starts it
        }
        function ImageLoader(images){
            this.images = images;
            this.current = 0;                 
            this.nextImage = function(){
                this.current = (this.current+1) % this.images.length;
                return this.images[this.current];;
            }
        }
        // Fill in images in this array
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(['img/wallpapers/2.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/3.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/4.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/5.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/6.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/7.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/9.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/10.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/11.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/12.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/13.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/14.jpg',  'img/wallpapers/15.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/16.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/17.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/18.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/19.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/20.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/21.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/22.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/23.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/24.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/25.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/26.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/27.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/28.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/29.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/30.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/31.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/32.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/33.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/34.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/35.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/36.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/37.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/38.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/39.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/40.jpg', 'img/wallpapers/41.jpg']);
        startCounter(imageLoader); // Set everything off! (Construct a new counter and starts it)
        });       
    </script>
<div id="middle_wallpaper-actual">              
            <img id="image" src="img/wallpapers/1.jpg" alt="wallpapers">                
          </div>
```

Comment: Please remove unnecessary spacing in your posts. It makes it easier to read. Also script should not be inside your containers when their presence there aren't making any difference. Move them to the head or end of page

Comment: Okay thanks, sorry new to this. Does it make a difference whether the scripts are in the head or body?

Comment: I personally prefer it in the head, there are those who swear to putting it before the </body> tag to speed up loading of the page but where you put it is annoying since it is in the middle of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Math.random` function to generate random numbers. For instance, to generate random numbers between `0` and `9`, you can do the following:

`var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);`

I have implemented an `ImageLoader` that will return random images and will **never return the same images until they all been shown**.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUZSZ/2/

```
function ImageLoader(images) {
    this.images = images;
    this.usedIndexes = {};
    this.displayedCount = 0;
}

ImageLoader.prototype.nextImage = function () {
    var self = this,
        len = self.images.length,
        usedIndexes = self.usedIndexes,
        lastBatchIndex = self.lastBatchIndex,
        denyLastBatchIndex = self.displayedCount !== len - 1,
        index;

    if (this.displayedCount === len) {
        lastBatchIndex = self.lastBatchIndex = self.lastIndex;
        usedIndexes = self.usedIndexes = {};
        self.displayedCount = 0;
    }

    do {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    } while (usedIndexes[index] || (lastBatchIndex === index && denyLastBatchIndex));

    self.displayedCount++;
    usedIndexes[self.lastIndex = index] = true;

    return self.images[index];
};
```

Comment: Thanks!! But where abouts would I put this in my code for it to work?

Comment: @user2297591, Just replace your own `ImageLoader` object definition by mine, basically  replace `function ImageLoader(images){...}` by the code above.

Comment: @user2297591, I'm glad I could help! Did it work? If it did please consider marking my answer as accepted ;) Thanks!

Comment: Oh right, aha sorry I'm new, and yeah I'm pretty sure it's working (:. But can I ask one more thing. Down the bottom in the html: "<img id="image" src="img/wallpapers/1.jpg" alt="wallpapers"> " Every time I open the page it will go to that ^ image. Is there a way I can tell it to just go to one of the random images mentioned above?

Comment: You can either set the `src` attribute of your image right when the page loads `$('#image').attr('src', imageLoader.nextImage())`, or you could use `setInterval` instead of the `countdown` plugin, or find a way to setup the plugin so that it calls the `callback` function as soon as the page loads.

Comment: Okay, so referring to the first option - is that like saying to make it run that nexImage as soon as the page loads? To do that would I just put this '$('#image').attr('src', imageLoader.nextImage())' under the  '$(document).ready(function() {' or? (Sorry for so many questions, I have little knowledge of js D;)

Comment: @user2297591, Yes you can put that in the document ready function. Btw, I fixed a bug in the code, so you should take that lastest version.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
this.current = (this.current+1) % this.images.length;
```

with

```
this.current = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
```